# floating TOC for prettydoc in Rmarkdown ask for theme

Tags: r, r-markdown

I love floating TOCs in my Rmarkdown and prettydoc package but trying to use both seems impossible.

I just want to add a floating TOC to my HTML Pretty doc. This is my working yaml header

```
title: "testing TOCs"
author: "Joe"
output:
  prettydoc::html_pretty:
    theme: leonids
    highlight: github
    toc: true
```

Adding Floating TOC option issues an error message asking for Theme.

```
title: "Test floating TOC"
author: "joe"
output:
  prettydoc::html_pretty:
    theme: leonids
    highlight: github
    toc: true
    toc_float: true


Error in rmarkdown::html_document(fig_retina = fig_retina, css = NULL,  : 
  You must use a theme when specifying the 'toc_float' option
Calls: <Anonymous> ... do.call -> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
```

Answer (score 3):

Per [GitHub](https://github.com/yixuan/prettydoc) documentation, toc_float does not work with prettydoc.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try `rmdformats`. It offers toc support and great visuals -
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmdformats/vignettes/introduction.html